# How To Play Back Certain Parts Of A WAV File Depending On Incoming Data?

Tags: python, mp3, wav

I am making a program that reads various data from a car, live.

While my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ does this over Bluetooth, it needs to read a wav file and play a certain parts depending on the RPM. But I don't know how to reference certain parts of the wav file using the RPM.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python's included [wav module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) to read the wave file and then, say, `wav_read.setpos` to set the position in the file (in bytes) and read the file from there.

Or, if you want to install it, [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) is higher level, and everything will be a bit easier, for example, you can use standard slice notation to specify a part of the file using milliseconds.

Once you have the part of the file, you could use a tool like [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) to play the data directly from your program, or you could write out a new file and make a system call from Python to play that new file.